# Ericsson NiMh battery - Klintland CF1330B

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

An old Ericcson GH388 uses a NiMH battery pack (Type 3008)

On the back of the battery, there are 3 contacts, named (+), (-) and (T).

[image: Type 3008 battery - back side]

While trying to change the battery, I noticed that the flexible pcb used to connect the contacts with the battery itself is a "MIDSIZE KLINTLAND CF1330B".

[image: MIDSIZE KLINTLAND CF1330B]

The question is, what is the purpose of the "T" terminal, and what is the blue part (which somewhat looks like a capacitor) bridging the "T" terminal with the "-" side of the battery.

Comment: Did you manage to change the battery? If so, what did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T is the terminal for the battery charging device to measure battery temperature with a temperature sensor. The blue part is the temperature sensor. The sensor resistance changes according to the temperature.